Pending Intent with unspecified mutability error while publishing the app to Play store with SDK 34
I was trying to publish the app with android sdk version 34,but it gave me error as Pending Intent with unspecified mutability. Can anyone help me how to resolve it ??
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
                0 /* Request code */, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }else {
        resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
                 0 /* Request code */, resultIntent,
                 PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
   }

This is my code reference

Are you sure that your error is Pending Intent with unspecified mutability ? Don't you mean Missing PendingIntent mutability flag ?

Your code is fine. You probably are using a library that is too old. Does the error from Google Play indicate where exactly in the code it has the issue with PendingIntent mutability? Are you getting this error when uploading to Google Play, or is this a build or runtime error?

Also, why are you setting PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT only with certain versions of Android? That doesn't sound right

Hey  , have you find any solution for this issue, I am facing same issue.
